# Add a class to each select options with SimpleForm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, select, simple-form

I want to build a `select` input from an array (and not a collection of models), with SimpleForm, and have different classes for each `option`s.

I would have hoped that this would work:

```
f.input :method, collection: [
    ["option text", "option_value_1", { class: "class_name_1" }],
    ["option text 2", "option_value_2", { class: "class_name_2" }]
]
```

The problem with that is it will generate:

```
<select>
    <option value="option text" class="class_name_1">option text</option>
    <option value="option text 2" class="class_name_2">option text 2</option>
</select>
```

How can I do what I want (value should be "option value") with simple form?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This appears to be a limitation when using collections, see the author of SimpleForm's explanation [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/385). He recommends a workaround of the form:

```
f.input :method, :as => :select do
  f.select :method, [['option text', 'option_value_1', {"class" => "class_name_1"}], ['option text 2', 'option_value_2', {"class" => "class_name_2"}]]
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Actually I had found a gh issue mentioning this thing, but it was dated 2 years ago, so I hoped things had changed.

Answer (score 2):

You also can pass array of arrays as an argument

```
= f.input :status, collection: [['option text', 'option_value_1', {"class" => "class_name_1"}], ['option text 2', 'option_value_2', {"class" => "class_name_2"}]]
```