# Get selected dropdown value inside form in view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Inside my simple_form in Rails, i want to have a dropdown to choose between different options. These options have a number associated to it, something like this:

```
[["spanish", 2], ["english", 3]]
```

so i want to put this in a dropdown inside a form to choose a language between the possible options.

How can i choose one of the languages, and then access the number associated with that option inside the same view? So if i choose "spanish", i can get the number 2 associated.

```
$('#sensor_selected').val();
```

I was doing this with jquery but its returning undefined, even if it returned the language, what i want is the number associated to it, not the name of the language.

Also, i dont know if it would be better to use it this way or use the helper select_chosen. Thank you for to anybody who can help me.

Comment: `<select id="sensor_selected"><option value="2">Spanish</option></select>` and `$('#sensor_selected').val() ///output: 2` should work.

Comment: This is in Rails, im using:

<%= f.input :device_sensor, collection: device_sensor_collection, required: true, input_html: {class: 'sensor_selected'}  %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15191153/12297707)

```
f.input :method, :as => :select do
  f.select :method, [['option text', 'option_value_1', {"class" => "class_name_1"}], ['option text 2', 'option_value_2', {"class" => "class_name_2"}]]
end


  $("#select_field_id").on("change", function(){
    var $option = $(this).find("option:selected");
  });
```

Comment: This was the thing i was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are selecting by ID and not Class if you are using a #

Comment: Omg, i lost 20 minutes of my life because i was doing the select as it was an id, thank you very much Pedro.